# Is there a way to make the output text copyable (Python PySimpleGUI)

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import random
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def password_generator(pw_len):
    password = "".join(random.sample(chars, pw_len))
    return password

chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789|!\"£$%&/()=?^é*ç°§;:_è+òàù,.-[]@#{}"
sg.theme('DarkPurple3')

layout = [[sg.Text('Password Generator', font=('Roboto', 20), justification='center')],
          [sg.Text('Set password length: ', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(size=(15, 1), key='length')],
          [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key='-OUTPUT-'), ],
          [sg.Button('Generate', size=(15, 1)), sg.Button('Exit', size=(15, 1))]]

window = sg.Window('Password Generator', layout)

while(True):
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == 'Generate' or sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        pw_len = int(values['length'])
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update('Your password: ' + password_generator(pw_len))

window.close()
```

Code Output: [password generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNTcQ.png)

Im trying to make a password generator that generate a passoword from the length chosen by the user. Everything works but i cant make the output text copyable, can someone explain me how to do it? Thank you in advance

Comment: One idea might be to offer a *"Copy"* button that writes it into the clipboard - use `pbcopy` or Applescript to write to clipboard on a Mac, maybe `xclip` on Linux...

Comment: For an operation that I know the user is likely to copy and paste, I go ahead and put the item on the clipboard for them so that it's ready to paste, and tell them that it's there.  An example is if you call `sg.get_versions()`.  The window tells you that the information is on the clipboard and ready to paste: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/46163555/162576061-43587032-b732-463d-ba20-52871cbcbb85.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of Text element cannot be selected and not copyable.

Using Input or Multiline element for it and set `disabled=True`.

For example

```py
sg.Input(size=(10,1), disabled=True, text_color=sg.theme_text_color(), disabled_readonly_background_color=sg.theme_text_element_background_color(), key='-OUTPUT-')
```